# How to temorary sudo within program?

Tags: linux, sudo

I wrote a file manager, and now I want to allow user to enter password if he want's to copy or edit a file that requires `sudo`. I can just start a new copy of a program with `gksudo` or `sudo` and hide the current copy. But is that possible to do in the same process?

I have read mans for `geteuid` and some other functions but I feel I lack some basic understanding here, because mans do not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do root-only stuff, process has to start with an effective uid of 0 or have capabilities that allow it to impersonate such euid (CAP_SETUID).

Effective uid is set using the special filesystem attribute, called "setuid" flag:

```
# ls -l /bin/su
-rws--x--x 1 root root 36720 Mar 28  2013 /bin/su
```

note the 's' in the file permission flags.

The above means, that when any user runs the `su` command, it will run on behalf of the executable's owner, in this case root (so the process will run with your normal user id, but effective user id will be that of `root` user). Thus, such process will be able to do anything `root` can.

Another, more modern approach, is to give the process select capabilities, such as `CAP_SETUID`. Those can be set and queried using `setcap`/`getcap` commands and allow finer grain control over what process can and can not do. Whether this results in safer system, remains an open question.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_File_Capabilities_Instead_Of_Setuid

Neat overview of possible security issues:

http://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2522&sid=c6fbcf62fd5d3472562540a7e608ce4e#p10271